# Why do we have to convert Bayes' net to MRF before applying Belief propagation?

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network, graph-theory, markov-random-field

is that even correct in the first place? if yes, then why? I've seen articles talking about inference in Bayes' nets, and I've seen others talking about conversion. I don't have the full picture.